# Git create branch where detached HEAD is

Tags: git, git-branch, git-detached-head

I tried something like this:

```
git branch temp
```

to create a new branch but *don't* move the `HEAD`. But I get:

```
# Not currently on any branch.
```

I don't want to merge anything, I just want a new branch at the current `HEAD`.

Answer (score 275, accepted):

You're sitting on a detached `HEAD`:

```
git checkout <sha>
```

You want to make a branch at that commit:

```
git branch my-new-branch
```

And now switch to that branch:

```
git checkout my-new-branch
```

Comment: Yes, but slightly simpler is `git checkout -b my-new-branch`.

Comment: @torek Yeah, that shorthand is quicker. I broke it into separate pieces because it looked like the OP was expecting `branch` to not only make the branch, but switch to it too. I wanted to make clear the difference between `branch` and `checkout`.

Comment: That shorthand is quicker to type, but slower to remember. I like the solution given.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use:

```
git switch -c <new branch name>
```

Comment: With modern Git, this should be the accepted answer.