# Merge or Rebase?

Tags: git, github

Here is my current commits.

```
commit1 - commit 2 - commit3 - commit4 - cmmit5 (my-app branch)
```

I checked out `commit1` and made changes

```
git checkout <commi1's SHA>
// made some changes
git add . && git commit -m "commit prime 1"
// made other changes
git add . && git commit -m "commit prime 2"
```

Now, I want to merge(?) or rebase(?) on the top of `my-app` branch.

I don't care about commit 5, I just want to put my currently changed `commit1` to the top of my-app branch (not merging but overriding!). So the output will be below

```
commit1 - commit 2 - commit3 - commit4 - cmmit5 - commit prime 1 - commit prime2" (my-app branch)
```

- I don't think I need to "merge" `commit 5` and `commit prime 2`.
- Maybe should I use rebase?

Here is my current terminal prompt:

```
jbaaa at jo's computer ~/directory on (HEAD detached from 8a36f955fc)*
```

git status output:

```
HEAD detached from 8a36f955fc
```

### nothing to commit, working tree clean.

Suppose commit5 is

```
'12345'
''
''
```

commit1 is

```
'1'
''
''
```

commit prime2 is

```
'1' 
'prime1 and prime2'
```

Final result must be

```
'1'
'prime1 and prime2'
```

If we `merge`, we're getting this result instead. How do we avoid it?

```
'12345'
'prime1 and prime2'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git create branch where detached HEAD is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366034/git-create-branch-where-detached-head-is)

Comment: @Makoto I'm not making any branch on this commit. :(

Comment: `git rebase my-app` will work.??? I"m afraid to use `rebase`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in a so called "HEAD detached" state, meaning your not working on a branch. First, put your current work into a branch.

```
git checkout -b my-feature
```

If you want to drop commit 5, rebase your work onto commit 4.

```
git rebase <commit4's SHA>
```

What you get will look like this:

```
c1 - c2 - c3 - c4 - c5 (my-app)
                \
                 p1 - p2 (my-feature)
```

As you don't care about commit 5, reset my-app to my-feature (p2).

```
git checkout my-app
git reset --hard my-feature
```

Final result:

```
                 c5 # no branch
                /
c1 - c2 - c3 - c4 - p1 - p2 (my-app, my-feature)
```

---

> I'm afraid to use rebase

If you are not sure about rebasing, leave your current branch untouched and create a new branch before you start to rebase, eg:

```
git checkout -b my-feature-rebased
```

Final result:

```
                 c5 # no branch
                /
c1 - c2 - c3 - c4 - p1 - p2 (my-app, my-feature-rebased)
 \
  p1 - p2 (my-feature) # backup
```

Comment: I don't think this works because I don't want commit prime 2 depends on commit5. If any additional line was made in commit 5, it will add up to merged commit.

Comment: The reason why I was thinking about `rebase` is that I want to 'move' `commit prime 1` and `commit prime 2`, and set the head of `my-app` branch to `commit prime 2`.

Comment: @JohnBaek You want "commit prime 1 - commit prime 2" to overwrite "cmmit5" ?

Comment: Please read the edited question. Hope this explains what I'm trying to say

Comment: Do you want to revert all commit 5 changes? Or one line only?

Comment: all 5 changes :)

Comment: Oh damn I found what you misunderstood,,, what I meant by "I don't care about commit5" was that p1 and p2 are not dependent to c2, c3, c4, c5 since p1 and p2 are from c1 commit.

Comment: But I think this pretty much explains well.

Answer (score -1):

you can use
`git rest --hard <commit1 hash>`
to move your head to commit1

Comment: you meant `commit prime 2`??